# Java Generic: How to extend a generic class of another generic class

Tags: java, generics

First, I have a simple template, nothing fancy:

```
public abstract class ListOfK<K> {
   private List<K> insides = new ArrayList<>(); 
}
```

Next, I'm creating a service interface using the template

```
public abstract interface SomeService<K extends ListOfK<K>> {
    int calculateSomething (K input);
    int calculateAnother (ListOfK<K> list);
}
```

So far so good with the abstraction.

Now, let's get to the implementation

```
public class ListOfString extends ListOfK<String> {

}
```

and implementation of SomeService:

```
public class SomeServiceImpl extends SomeService<String> {
  @Override
  public int calculateSomething(String input) {
    return 0;  // TODO impl
  }

  @Override
  public int calculateAnother(ListOfK listOfK) {
    return 0;  // TODO impl
  }
}
```

Somehow, when `SomeServiceImpl` extends `SomeService<String>`, it marks  `Type parameter java.lang.String is not within its bound; should extend ListOfK<String>`

What should I input as implementation of `SomeService` so it doesn't give error? Or do I make mistake with SomeService? I just want a class whom input is a another class using Generic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you think `SomeService<K extends ListOfK<K>>` means?

Comment: an interface named `SomeService` registering `K` as generic while using class `ListOfK` please correct me if I'm wrong. I tried `SomeService<ListOfK<K>>` but it doesn't give.

Comment: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/5515060)

Comment: What do you mean by _using class_? Using it how/where? What role does the `extends` keyword play?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it utilizes `ListOfK` in its process, for example later in the form of method ```int calculateSomething (K input);
    int calculateAnother (ListOfK<K> list);```

Comment: `SomeService<String>` is invalid, because `K` cannot be `String`, because you said `K` must be a `ListOfK`, and `String` does not extend from `ListOfK`. This would be a problem even if it weren't for the recursive use of `K` in the definition of `K`.

Comment: @DanielPryden Change it into `public class SomeServiceImpl extends SomeService<ListOfString>` doesn't solve it either, the message becomes  `Type parameter ListOfString is not within its bound; should extend ListOfK<ListOfString>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key insight here is that `K` in the context of the `ListOfK` class is not the same type as `K` in the context of the `SomeService` class. In fact, in your definition of `SomeService`, you're saying that `K` needs to itself be a `ListOfK`, which I suspect is your problem.

- Does `calculateSomething` need to take (1) a single value, or (2) a `ListOfK` of values?
- Does `calculateAnother` need to take (1) a `ListOfK` of values, or (2) a `ListOfK` of `ListOfK` values?

I think you *want* option 1, but you've actually chosen option 2.

To fix this, don't constrain `K` in `SomeService`:

```
public interface SomeService<K> {
    int calculateSomething(K input);
    int calculateAnother(ListOfK<K> list);
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you @daniel-pryden. You're right, I want option 1 but somehow got myself option 2. Thanks again :)

Answer (score -1):

The issue lies in the way you are defining the `SomeService` interface. Your code of `<K extends ListOfK<K>>` says that "we need a class `K` which extends `ListOfK`, which uses `K` as its type parameter." So that class would have to look something like:

```java
public class Test extends ListOfK<Test> {
```

Which doesn't make any sense. It shouldn't only use itself inside of the list. If you change the interface to something like:

```java
public abstract interface SomeService<K extends ListOfK<?>> {
```

It should fix your issue.

Comment: You say that that code "doesn't make any sense" but that's not true. There are definitely good use cases for recursive parameterized types. Using an unbounded type wildcard is not a good solution (probably better to introduce a new type variable instead, in most cases).